# Mixing net5.0 and c++ in cmake project?

Tags: c#, c++, cmake

I am trying to build a mixed native/c# project using cmake.

Basic steps to reproduce:

```
$ touch bar.cs
$ touch app.cxx
```

If you now try to build in Visual Studio 2019 the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(
  Example
  VERSION 0.1.0
  LANGUAGES CXX CSharp)

add_library(foo SHARED bar.cs)

# we want nullable:
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_LangVersion "8.0")

set_target_properties(
  foo
  PROPERTIES DOTNET_SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk"
             DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK "net5.0"
             VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES
             "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions_5.0.0")

add_executable(app app.cxx)
```

You'll get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
> framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" in the
> "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
> restore.  app C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\16.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets   198

[image]

Question: how can I use cmake to build my C# + C++ code ?

---

```
> cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3
```